# How to get Firebase Realtime Database reference from Unity Desktop build?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make the Firebase Realtime Database works on Unity Desktop build for debugging. When I run the code below in the Unity Editor, everything works correctly and I was able to get the database reference and use GetValueAsync() to download data from it. But when I tried the same code in a Desktop build for Windows, I am constantly getting the null reference error for the database reference. Could someone help, please?

```
myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;

Debug.Log("Database: " + myDatabase);
```

**UPDATE:**

0.The `Assets/Services/StreamingAssets/google-services-desktop.json` was there the whole time, sorry for not mentioned it in the post.

1.I tried to place a duplicate of it in different places of the build but still couldn't make it work.

2.I also tested this problem in a mac build and it also couldn't find the Database reference.

3.I copy-pasted relevant bits out manually and finally **made it work**.

4.I also tried to load the config manually but keep getting this error, I think I might be doing wrong though.

`Failed to parse Firebase config: (1, 1): error: declaration expected. Check the config string passed to App::CreateFromJsonConfig()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on without logging, so definitely try capturing it in the debugger/in a terminal if this doesn't help. I went and verified that this works, but on macOS desktop. So Windows support may vary, and I'll try to cover that.

I suspect that you're missing or can't find `google-services-desktop.json` (or `google-services.xml`). What I'd recommend doing is checking to see if `Assets/Services/StreamingAssets/google-services-desktop.json` has been generated. If it hasn't, try switching to either Android or iOS, running in the editor (or doing a build if that doesn't generate it), then switching back to desktop and running.

Now if that doesn't work (or you already have `google-services-desktop.json`), the next step would be to see if it's not loading it correctly. The Firebase SDK will automatically look for this file when you try to grab `DefaultInstance`, but the logic to do so is in the [C++ underpinnings](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk) of the Firebase SDK. Specifically, you can see the code to load this on the desktop [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/b1ba676cebab594b7ca50b06285699998a561f30/app/src/app_desktop.cc#L90). When I inspect my MacOS app directory, I see `google-services-desktop.json` under `Contents/Resources/Data/StreamingAssets/` (MacOS `.app` programs are actually just folders under the hood) -- if you see the file in a similar directory on Windows you can try copy/pasting it into the same directory as your game's `.exe` file. The guess being that maybe the behaviour for finding this differs between OSes. If that occurs, file a bug [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) and feel free to link this post and tag me on GitHub (patm1987).

One last thing to try is that if you call [`FirebaseApp.Create`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#class_firebase_1_1_firebase_app_1aaeb3418d9c118fcb63a409ee05a5e4aa) with no app name before you do anything in Firebase, you get to specify how the "default" app is configured. You can configure the `AppOptions` manually or load from json using [`AppOptions.LoadFromJsonConfig`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/app-options#loadfromjsonconfig). Because the Firebase singleton is lazily initialized, you will have to be *very careful* if you do this. Here's what your code might look like:

```
var dependencyStatus = await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();
if (dependencyStatus != DependencyStatus.Available) {
    // error handling here. Quit the game or run without Firebase
}

// copy paste relevant bits out manually
var appOptions = new AppOptions {
    .ApiKey = "api-key-from-config",
    .AppId = "app-id-from-config",
    .DatabaseUrl = "database-url-from-config",
    .MessageSenderId = "message-sender-id", // probably can be left out
    .ProjectId = "project-id-from-config",
    .StorageBucket = "storage-bucket-from-config" // probably can be left out if you're not using storage
}

// OR load the config manually
// var appOptions = AppOptions.LadFromJsonConfig($"{Application.dataPath}/StreamingAssets/google-services-desktop.json");

var app = FirebaseApp.Create(appOptions);
// now FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance will also be your configured application

myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(app);
// can also do myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance, but this is more explicit
```

If this latter solution works and nothing above did, I'd also ask that you post a bug report [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) to make sure it gets on the team's radar.

Comment: The latter solution ended up solving the problem, thanks for your help! I have the detailed information updated in my post and I will definitely post a bug report soon.